# Winforms: Determine if the mouse cursor is leaving the boundary of a modal dialog

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is it possible to determine, if a **mouse cursor** is leaving a **custom modal Winforms dialog** (the mouse cursor is entering the space around the dialog)? The dialog is shown via ShowDialog(). Mouse_Leave doesn't work, because it fires when leaving the visible part of the form. Therefore it also fires, when entering a control on the form!

Comment: yes it is. what effort have you made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Form's MouseLeave event won't always fire if the form has Panels that dock-fill the client area, so a Timer is a fairly reliable way to check this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
  timer.Enabled = true;
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (this.Bounds.Contains(MousePosition)) {
    this.Text = "Inside";
  } else {
    this.Text = "Outside";
  }
}
```

Comment: Careful, this timer keeps ticking after the form is disposed.

Answer (score 0):

WinForm dialog is Form so answer would be YES. You need to hook up on appropriate events to register leaving and entering the dialog just as you would on any form.